# Find the origin of "Ratio has zero denominator" Exception

Tags: debugging, haskell

As a personal excercize in the process of learning **Haskell**, I'm trying to port this **F#** snippet for [Random Art](http://fssnip.net/si).

I've not embedded full source code for not bloating the question, but is available as [gist](https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/20a88f635ad8cb25d9d1).

An important part of the program is this `Expr` type:

```
data Expr =
    VariableX
  | VariableY
  | Constant
  | Sum Expr Expr
  | Product Expr Expr
  | Mod Expr Expr
  | Well Expr
  | Tent Expr
  | Sin Expr
  | Level Expr Expr Expr
  | Mix Expr Expr Expr
  deriving Show
```

and two functions:

- `gen :: Int -> IO Expr` random generates a *tree-like* structure given a number of iterations
- `eval :: Expr -> IO (Point -> Rgb Double)` walks the tree and terminates producing a drawing function.

More high is the number passed to `gen` than higher are the probability that the following exception is generated: `Ratio has zero denominator`.

I'm new to Haskell so to solve the problem I've tried to compile it as above:

```
ghc RandomArt.hs -prof -auto-all -caf-all
```

Obtaining only this more (to me quite useless) info:

```
$ ./RandomArt +RTS -xc

*** Exception (reporting due to +RTS -xc): (THUNK_STATIC), stack trace:
  GHC.Real.CAF
  --> evaluated by: Main.eval.\,
  called from Main.eval,
  called from Main.tga.pxs',
  called from Main.tga,
  called from Main.save,
  called from Main.main,
  called from :Main.CAF:main
  --> evaluated by: Main.eval.\.r,
  called from Main.eval.\,
  called from Main.eval,
  called from Main.tga.pxs',
  called from Main.tga,
  called from Main.save,
  called from Main.main,
  called from :Main.CAF:main
*** Exception (reporting due to +RTS -xc): (THUNK_STATIC), stack trace:
  Main.tga,
  called from Main.save,
  called from Main.main,
  called from GHC.Real.CAF
RandomArt: Ratio has zero denominator
```

The code that persist the generated function to a **TGA** file works because it was my [previous excercize](https://gist.github.com/gsscoder/41df52d9b2f9c29f29f7) (a port from **OCaml**).

I've tried executing various `Expr` tree from **GHCi**, assembling data by *hand* or applying functions as in the program but I wasn't able to identify the bug.

Haskell docs talks about a package named `loch` that should able to compile preserving source code line numbers, but I was not able to install it (while I normally install with `cabal install` every package I need).

The question, to be honest are two:

- where's is the bug (in this specific case)?
- which tool do I need to master to find bugs like this (or bugs in general)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say that you tried to generate trees by hand but you were unable to identify the bug you mean that you didn't get any error or that you did get the error but you were unable to understand why you got the error with that tree? In the latter case please provide the inputs you tried.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I've tried composing the tree like `let e = Sum (Constant (Well VariableY))` or `e <- gen X` (where X is normally 10, 20 ... 50)` and than `f <- eval e. This allowed me to test `f` typing: `f(3.2, 0,34)` in **GHCi**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The exception

Let's focus on the exception first.

### Finding the bug

> where's is the bug (in this specific case)?

In `mod'`. We can check this easily if we provide an alternative version instead of the one by `Data.Fixed`:

```
mod' :: RealFrac a => a -> a -> a
mod' _ 0 = error "Used mod' on 0"
mod' a b =
    let k = floor $ a / b
    in a - (fromInteger k) * b
```

We now get `Used mod' on 0`.

### Rationale

> which tool do I need to master to find bugs like this (or bugs in general)?

In this case, the necessary hint was already in the exception's message:

> ```
> Ratio has zero denominator
> ```

This means that there's a place where you divide by zero in the context of a [`Ratio`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#t:Ratio). So you need to look after all places where you divide something. Since you use only `(/)` and `mod'`, it boils down to whether one of them actually *can* throw this exception:

- `(/)` usually returns `±Infinity` on division by zero if used on `Double`,
- `mod'` uses `toRational` internally, which is a `Ratio Integer`.

So there's only one culprit left. Note that the other implementation yields the same results if `b` isn't zero.

## The *actual* problem

Using `mod` or `mod'` with `b == 0` isn't well-defined. After all, a [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) should hold the following property:

```
prop_mod :: Integral n => n -> n -> Bool
prop_mod a b = 
  let m = a `mod` b
      d = a `div` b

  in a == b * d + m   -- (1)
     && abs m < abs b -- (2)
```

If `b == 0`, there doesn't exist any pair `(d, m)` such that (1) **and** (2) hold. If we relax this law and throw (2) away, the result of `mod` isn't necessarily unique anymore. This leads to the following definition:

```
mod' :: RealFrac a => a -> a -> a
mod' a 0 = a -- this is arbitrary
mod' a b =
    let k = floor $ a / b
    in a - (fromInteger k) * b
```

However, this is an arbitrary definition. You have to ask yourself, "What do I actually want to do if I cannot use `mod` in a sane way". Since F# apparently didn't complain about `a % 0`, have a look at their documentation.

Either way, you cannot use a library `mod` function, since they aren't defined for a zero denominator.

Comment: Small caveat: `(/0)` is perfectly capable of raising that error if you use it on `Rational` rather than floating point. Although in this case the OP doesn't seem to be using `Rational` except indirectly through `mod'`.

Comment: @Zeta, +1 and this answers. At this point what this the more correct way to fix this bug? Just prevents that `mod'` is applied with a second argument equal to `0`?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen True. After all, `mod'` uses `/` on `Rational` via `div'`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: +1 for further clarification on `mod'` and `Rational`.

Comment: @Zeta, what do you mean with alternative `mod'` variant? To what variant you're referring? The one in your post?

Comment: @gsscoder: Finally had some coffee, I wrote my answer yesterday just before I went to bed. I've checked some things, and you actually use `mod' a 0` somewhere, where I thought you used `mod' a someVerySmallValueCloseToZero`. This is the actual source of your error, sorry for the confusion. Basically, `mod a 0` doesn't make sense from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: I want to add that it finally works, as soon I'll add the 1..1000 loop to generate more images. Now I post to Gist the fixed code. Thansk to everyone helped and explained.

Comment: @Zeta, but my implementation is a port of **F#**... Also the **F#** version has this problem? Because now I can generate one image with `gen 50`.